Changing coordinates of $2$nd order partial operators
Let's work in $\mathbf R^n$. If we want to change coordinates $\mathbf x\to\mathbf r$, with them related like
$$
\mathbf x=\mathbf x(\mathbf r)
$$
Then, the second order generic partial operator in the new coordinates would be
$$
\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i\partial x_j}&=\left(\dfrac{\partial r_\ell}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_\ell}\right)\left(\dfrac{\partial r_k}{\partial x_j}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_k}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\partial r_\ell}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_\ell}\left(\dfrac{\partial r_k}{\partial x_j}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_k}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\partial r_\ell}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial^2 r_k}{\partial r_\ell\partial x_j}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r_k}+\dfrac{\partial r_\ell}{\partial x_i}\dfrac{\partial r_\ell}{\partial x_j}\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial r_\ell\partial r_k}
\end{aligned}
$$
Is there any way to express this in vector/matrix notation, especially the second term?

Suggestion: instead of working with the abstract operators, apply them to a function $f$ and you will find the answer relating the Hessian of $f$ in one set of coordinates to the Hessian of $f$ in the other coordinate system.

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\hess#1#2#3{\grad{^2 #1}{#2\,\p #3}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\hessLR#1#2#3{\LR{\hess{#1}{#2}{#3}}}
\def\O{\Omega}
$Write the target expression in index notation
$$\eqalign{
\hess\phi{r_p}{r_q}
 \;=\; \gradLR{x_i}{r_p} \hessLR\phi{x_i}{x_j} \gradLR{x_j}{r_q}
 \;+\; \gradLR\phi{x_k} \hessLR{x_k}{r_p}{r_q}
}$$
Define the gradient vector and Hessian matrix
with respect to each coordinate system
$$\eqalign{
g_i &= \grad{\phi}{x_i}, \qq &H_{ij} = \hess\phi{x_i}{x_j} \\
f_p &= \grad{\phi}{r_p}, \qq &M_{pq} = \hess\phi{r_p}{r_q} \qq \qq
}$$
and Jacobian of the coordinate transform
and its derivative (a third-order tensor!)
$$\eqalign{
A_{ip} &= \grad{x_i}{r_p}, \qq \O_{ipq} = \grad{A_{ip}}{r_q}= \hess{x_i}{r_p}{r_q} \\
}$$
Combine everything into a single vector-matrix-tensor equation
$$\eqalign{
M \;=\; A^THA \;+\; g\cdot\O \\
}$$
I'm not sure if that's what you had in mind, but there it is.

I see, it actually makes more sense to apply the operator to some function as in the case of $2$nd order PDEs. Last question: in the second term, $g\cdot\Omega$, I'm guessing $\cdot$ represents a contraction in the $k$ index?

Yes, it is a contraction. The order of the terms in my first equation (using index notation) is identical to those of the final equation (using matrix-tensor notation).
